# Double Click Python EXE run properly but Call from VBA raise Error No.2 No such directory file

Tags: python, vba, excel, matplotlib

I have a python script that uses Openpyxl to load worbook.xlsm for data entry and print chart by using Matplotlib. I convert the script to exe using Py2exe.

It's weird when I double-click the program, it runs perfectly. Call that program on VBA raise the directory of workbook.xlsm is not found. Both program file and workbook are in the same directory.

Can anyone explain to me how I can figure it out?

Update: Please see my code as attached.[myscript.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AR-P8VwF41APTu7rahja8jyWE_TN7uTA)

Comment: It's impossible for anyone (including you) to troubleshoot without seeing your code and *stepping* through it line by line.

Comment: Maybe your script relies on the current directory being set to some specific value.  Make sure you're not making any assumptions about that...

Comment: @ashleedawg, I upload my script as attached.  It's not a large program. I remember I could run one or two times before. Now not work at all.

Comment: I don't know what is the magic behind it. This time I use Pyinstaller and compile to one file. Now it works lol .